# Please help guide new users with reviews

Tags: discussion, reviews

The [First Posts](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts) and [Late Answers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers) review queues are really important -- the first contains new users' first attempts to participate on Writers, and the second contains posts from lower-reputation users that have tickled older posts.  In both cases, just being ignored can be pretty discouraging.<sup>1</sup>  We want people with quality contributions to have a good experience here, and we want people who need a little help learning the ropes to get that help.

Both of these queues currently have more than 20 items waiting for review -- 40+ posts between the two waiting for a helpful comment, an encouraging vote, a correcting edit, or the occasional "don't do that again" downvote.  You only need 350 reputation for these two queues.  You can review one or two at a time; you don't have to commit a lot of time at once.  There's a "skip" button if you don't know what to do with a particular entry.

Won't you consider helping out our new users?

<sup>1</sup> See [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167510/162102):

> A couple years ago now, we did some analysis of new user retention on Stack Overflow. Some forms of feedback tended to result in folks coming back more than others, but the single biggest way to keep someone away was to just ignore them. Don't vote - up or down. Don't comment. Don't answer. Don't close. Just... ignore. While you're busy walking on eggshells in fear of offending someone, they're seeing a blank page, an empty inbox, and they're walking away.

Answer (score 5):

I just went through the entire queue. Thanks for the reminder — I had stopped looking at review queues about a year ago after I burned out over at GDSE when every. single. review. was "Send this to Stack Overflow because it's about 'my Adobe be broke,' not Graphic Design." But we don't have that kind of problem here (a number of "migrate to English," but nowhere near as bad), so I should get back on the stick.